# Is there a FOR XML variant that can add attributes with arbritrary values?

Tags: sql-server, xml

I'm trying to create a query similar to this

```
SELECT
'foo' AS Detail,
'bar' AS Detail,
'baz' AS Detail
FOR XML PATH ('Header')
```

To produce something like this-

```
<Header>
  <Detail type="A">foo</Detail>
  <Detail type="B">bar</Detail>
  <Detail type="C">baz</Detail>
</Header>
```

and it seems like there's no way to create attributes without assigning column values into them.

Answer (score 6):

The query you have

```sql
SELECT
'foo' AS Detail,
'bar' AS Detail,
'baz' AS Detail
FOR XML PATH ('Header')
```

concatenates the values to a single `Detail` element.

```xml
<Header>
  <Detail>foobarbaz</Detail>
</Header>
```

To have multiple `Detail` elements you need to separate the columns with a `null`.

```sql
SELECT
'foo' AS Detail,
 null,
'bar' AS Detail,
 null,
'baz' AS Detail
FOR XML PATH ('Header')
```

```xml
<Header>
  <Detail>foo</Detail>
  <Detail>bar</Detail>
  <Detail>baz</Detail>
</Header>
```

And then you use the `@` syntax suggested in the [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/120376/2103) by Rob Farley to get the result you are looking for.

```sql
SELECT
'A' AS 'Detail/@type', 
'foo' AS Detail,
 null,
'B' AS 'Detail/@type', 
'bar' AS Detail,
 null,
'C' AS 'Detail/@type', 
'baz' AS Detail
FOR XML PATH ('Header')
```

```xml
<Header>
  <Detail type="A">foo</Detail>
  <Detail type="B">bar</Detail>
  <Detail type="C">baz</Detail>
</Header>
```

Comment: You can also use CASE statements to conditionally add the attributes, e.g. negative numbers in red font

Answer (score 3):

Try naming your column `[@type]`

Multiple rows might help too. Something like:

```
SELECT 'A' as [@type], 'foo'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B' as [@type], 'bar'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'C' as [@type], 'baz'
FOR XML PATH('Detail'), ROOT('Header');
```